# Exoplayer app crash when using gesture control

Tags: java, android, gesture, exoplayer2.x

I am using exoplayer to stream a video file video plays correctly but when i try to implement gesture control like swipe up, swipe down, double tap the app crashes. simply put when i swipe up or swipe down the app crashes and the double tap is not working at all.
My exoplayer activity

```
        GESTURECONTROLLER gcont = new GESTURECONTROLLER();
        gcont.setActivity(this);
        gestureDetectorCompat = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, gcont);

        LoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl();

        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));

        simpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, loadControl);

        playerView.setPlayer(simpleExoPlayer);

        DefaultDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, "demo"));

        MediaSource contentMediaSource = buildMediaSource(streamLink);
        MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[1];
        mediaSources[0] = contentMediaSource;

        MediaSource mediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(mediaSources);

        simpleExoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
        simpleExoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
        playerView.setKeepScreenOn(true);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        gestureDetectorCompat.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    public void ifDoubleTap() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I double tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void ifSwipeLeft() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I swipe Left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void ifSwipeRight() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I swipe Right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void ifSwipeUp() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I swipe Up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public void ifSwipeDown() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "I swipe Down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

My Gesture Controller Class

```
public class GESTURECONTROLLER extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static int MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE_X = 100;
    private static int MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE_Y = 100;

    private static int MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE_X = 1000;
    private static int MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE_Y = 1000;

    private MainActivity activity = null;

    public MainActivity getActivity(){
        return activity;
    }

    public void setActivity(MainActivity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        float deltaX = e1.getX() - e2.getX();
        float deltaY = e1.getY() - e2.getY();

        float deltaXabs = Math.abs(deltaX);
        float deltaYabs = Math.abs(deltaY);

        if (deltaXabs >= MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE_X && deltaXabs <= MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE_X){
            if(deltaX > 0 ) {
                //Swipe Left
              this.activity.ifSwipeLeft();
            } else {
                //Swipe Right
               this.activity.ifSwipeRight();
            }
        }

        if (deltaYabs >= MIN_SWIPE_DISTANCE_Y && deltaYabs <= MAX_SWIPE_DISTANCE_Y){
            if(deltaY > 0 ) {
                //Swipe Up
                this.activity.ifSwipeUp();
            } else {
            //Swipe Down
                this.activity.ifSwipeDown();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
        this.activity.IfSingletap();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        this.activity.ifDoubleTap();
        return true;
    }
```

I am aware on the default touch controls that comes hardcoded with exoplayer library but i can i disable that and use this controls instead

Comment: Could you post the log?

Comment: @Louis Nguyen I can't am using a physical device

Comment: Could you check null for activity in GESTURECONTROLLER?

Comment: @LouisNguyen how do i try that

Comment: Maybe check null activity before use it like below:

if(this.activity != null){
this.activity.ifSwipeLeft();}

Comment: Activity is not null app still crashes I also tested it with a video player and all swipes and taps were working perfectly and accordingly but when I used the same class on exoplayer the app crashed